# I want to merge 2 excel sheets based on Date and Time?

Tags: python

I have 2 dataframes where the first dataframe contains 2 columns i.e. Date and Time. 
The second dataframe contains multiple columns i.e. Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close. 
I want to merge the second dataframe to the first on the basis of Date and Time. Here is the code below

First dataframe -

```
    Date    Time
0   2015-02-02  09:15:00
1   2015-02-02  09:16:00
2   2015-02-02  09:17:00
3   2015-02-02  09:18:00
4   2015-02-02  09:19:00
... ... ...
447380  2019-12-10  15:25:00
447381  2019-12-10  15:26:00
447382  2019-12-10  15:27:00
447383  2019-12-10  15:28:00
447384  2019-12-10  15:29:00
```

second dataframe -

```
open    high     low   close  volume Symbol    Date     Time
121.00  121.00  121.00  121.00  0     ABFRL 2015-02-02   09:15:00
123.00  123.00  120.20  120.20  0     ABFRL 2015-02-02   09:16:00
120.20  120.20  120.20  120.20  0     ABFRL 2015-02-02   09:17:00
120.20  120.20  120.20  120.20  0     ABFRL 2015-02-02   09:18:00
120.20  120.20  120.20  120.20  0     ABFRL 2015-02-02   09:19:00
```

Main code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime

file = pd.read_excel("D:\\Aman\\bn trading.xlsx")
file.info()


total = os.listdir("D:\\Aman\\Data\\Stocks Data 2015-2019 (1 min)")
for i in total:
    stockfile = pd.read_csv("D:\\Aman\\Data\\Stocks Data 2015-2019 (1 min)\\"+i)
    stockfile["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(stockfile["Date"])
    stockfile.info()

    final = pd.merge(file,stockfile[["close","Date","Time"]],how = "left",on = ("Date","Time") )

final
```

The above code is giving me empty dataframe as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the below as

```
    final = pd.merge(file,stockfile[["close","Date","Time"]],how = "outer",on = ["Date","Time"] )
```

This will show NaN for items that do not match in your set on either left or right.

Comment: I want to take the "left " dataframe as a base for date and time.

Comment: Are they both of the same datetime formats or string format?

Comment: convert as such.
```
file['Date'] = file['Date'].astype(str)
file['Time'] = file['Time'].astype(str)
stockfile['Date'] = stockfile['Date'].astype(str)
stockfile['Time'] = stockfile['Time'].astype(str)
```
And then use ```pd.merge(file,stockfile[["close","Date","Time"]],how = "left",on = ["Date","Time"] )```

Comment: It works. Thanks.  How do I set the column name to the file name of the second dataframe from where close has been taken?

Comment: There is no use adding it as a column name, But Add a field as source and Set it to the file name.

```
file['source'] = "D:\\Aman\\bn trading"
```
Also Leave an upvote if you found this useful, so that others can find the same answer when they search next time.

Comment: Well, I need to merge 20 more dataframes close column to the first dataframe. Therefore in such a case, I need to rename the respective close column with that of file name

Comment: Then you can keep it in an iteration and name your columns as such ```stockfile['close'] = <your-filename-here>```